# JMeter did not execute the properly the # of users using Jenkins parameterization

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, load-testing, parameterization

I set up a Jenkins to integrate the JMeter script. Using the Freestyle project in Jenkins, I enabled "This project is parameterized" to set a String parameters for the Threads, Loop_Count and Think Time.

- In .jmx file, I used the Function Parameters function to define those
  variables, as shown below image:
  [User Defined Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3OMa.jpg)
- In Jenkins, I configured the parameterization as shown below:
  [Set Parameterization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86OCu.jpg)
  [Command Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlHh2.jpg)

However, when running the test for 40 users using the Build parameter in Jenkins, it looks like the # of threads/users are not correct that is being executed, the Samples that are being generated only 3 for most of the pages. Only the Homepage (which is the first page on the test) is only getting the correct # of Samples, but the rest of the URLS/pages are not correct. Below the actual output.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ACtA.jpg)

Can you please help what might the causing this issue, I already checked the Jmeter script and jenkins config and appears to be correct but still I'm getting the issue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Setting parameters in Jenkins itself is not sufficient to pass them to JMeter, you need to pass this parameterized value to JMeter startup script via [`-J` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

```
-Jusers=%users%
```

[image]

End-to-end demo:

[image]

More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: I did pass the parameter to the Jmeter startup script through Execute Windows batch command line script and still getting the same result. Please advise. 

Here's the sample coomand:

cd "C:\JMeter\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin"
jmeter -Jusers=%Users% -JThink_Time=%Think_Time% -JLoop_count=%Loop_count% -jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml


Please advise.